# How to convert columns to rows in AWS Athena or python?

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Please consider this table:

| ID | Name | Sector |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/5/3/4 | NA/SA/TE/CV/BA | 0/0/1953525168/0/0 |

I want to convert this table to this one:

| ID | Name | Sector |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | 0 |
| 2 | SA | 0 |
| 5 | TE | 1953525168 |
| 3 | CV | 0 |
| 4 | BA | 0 |

...

How I can do this in appropriate way and put the query into AWS glue job ETL script?

Comment: if space and / is only delimeter should be trivial. 
split them twice then iterate through the items and place them in a new variable.
x = txt.split(" ", 5)[0].split("/",6)[0]
y = txt.split(" ", 5)[1].split("/",6)[0]
z = txt.split(" ", 5)[2].split("/",6)[0]
a = txt.split(" ", 5)[3].split("/",6)[0]
b = txt.split(" ", 5)[4].split("/",6)[0]

Comment: Hi @agent_bean , actually / is only the delimeter. And there are 100,00+ rows in the table, I don't think is workable to write line by line. Any other ways to write? Thnx

Comment: you don't have to write it line by line, just 1 function. to split the string and transpose it. if you have access to pandas you can use that library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split`'s into [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (ID, Name, Sector) AS (
    VALUES ('1/2/5/3/4', 'NA/SA/TE/CV/BA', '0/0/1953525168/0/0')
)

-- query
select t.*
from dataset
,unnest (split(ID, '/'), split(Name, '/'), split(Sector, '/')) as t(ID, Name, Sector);
```

Output:

| ID | Name | Sector |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | 0 |
| 2 | SA | 0 |
| 5 | TE | 1953525168 |
| 3 | CV | 0 |
| 4 | BA | 0 |